# Can I log in to multiple X sessions with a SINGLE user?

Tags: xorg, vnc

I want to know whether I can log in to multiple X sessions in a single machine with a SINGLE user account.

For example, I hope:

1. User "John" creates an X session with TigerVNC and connects to it remotely.
2. User "John" also creates an X session locally. He does not want to terminate the remote session as he logs in, but that's the case by default.

As far as I know, the termination is caused by some mechanism that prevents a single user from logging in to multiple GUI sessions. Is there a way to bypass that limitation?

Comment: I've read a few things recently that *seem* to suggest this feature is broken - to do with how systemd + PAM allocate DBUS sessions per-user rather than per-session? See for example [creation of session service type #24932](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/24932). But I may be misunderstanding.